# sed replace xml header

Tags: regex, xml, sed, redhat

I am using redhat linux, and generated a huge XML document by doing something like

```
while read -r Id; do
curl -X Get "http://ip/api >> $outputfilename
done
```

then the result file is something like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

now I would want to remove the `?xml` headers and the interim tags so target file should be like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
<somemanytags/>
<somemanytags/>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

I tried in vi, when I do something like `?<\?xml\ version=\'1\.0\'\ encoding=\'UTF\-8\'\?` it can match with `xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'` however it cannot seem to be able to match beyond that point. Also I have tried `sed -i -e "s/xml\ version\'1\.0\'\ encoding=\'UTF\-8\'//g" outputfilename.xml` but it does not seem to work on the file. May I know if there is anyway to do this in sed?

Answer (score 1):

If you had a well formed XML I would have used `XSLT` or another XML technology to clean this up.

If you go for a `sed` solution, you can use:

**INPUT:**

```
cat broken_xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
sed -E "/PurchaseOrder/s/<\?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'\?>//g" broken_xml 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder>
<PurchaseOrder>
<somemanytags/>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

Comment: Thank you`sed -E -i "/PurchaseOrder/s/<\?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'\?>//g" output.xml` solved majority of the issue, I can handle the rest with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^<\/PurchaseOrder><?xml/,/^<PurchaseOrder>/d' file
```

An alternative:

```
sed '3,${/<\/\?PurchaseOrder>/!p;$!d}' file
```